# SQL Computed Column Case with Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble using Case statement for multiple criteria, I don't know how to nest another CASE.

- `DateTime` column: `Control_OpenDateOwner`
- `DateTime` column: `Control_ClosedDateRev`

Computed column:

```
(case when [Control_ClosedDateRev] IS NULL then '1' else '0' end)
```

Trying to I want to calculate when the `OPENDATE` is greater than 4 Days opened (using `today()`) and the close date is Null, put a `1` (open record and has more than 4 days opened or `0` if the record is closed or less than 4 days opened, I can't get it to work.

Why?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: 'today' is not a recognized built-in function name. per MATT BUSCHE code which i found simple.

Comment: There is no such a function on sql-server. You could use `getdate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` in a `CASE` statement. You don't need to perform a true nested `CASE` statement in this scenario

```
(CASE WHEN [Control_ClosedDateRev] IS NULL 
       AND DateDiff(day,opendate,getDate()) > 4 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
```

Comment: i get an "validation error", 'today' is not a recognized built-in function name.